# Reload .bashrc with Dockerfile

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, dockerfile

I have created a custom alias to run powershell in linux. for that I have created a docker image with that alias. but when a container started with that image my custom alias not working as expected. I had to use `source .bashrc` to reload the .bashrc and then it worked. I need to reload this .bashrc inside the Dockerfile. any advice ideas much appreciated.

```
WORKDIR /home/releases
USER root

RUN   echo "alias powershell='pwsh'" >> .bashrc
#NTRYPOINT [ "bash","/opt/slave-launch.sh"]
RUN  apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y wget \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# Download the Microsoft repository GPG keys
RUN wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb

# Register the Microsoft repository GPG keys
RUN dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb

# Update the list of products
RUN apt-get update

# Install PowerShell
RUN apt-get install -y powershell

# Install Vim editor
RUN apt-get install vim -y

RUN source /etc/.bashrc

#ENTRYPOINT [ "bash","-c","sleep 2000"]
ENTRYPOINT [ "bash","/opt/slave-launch.sh"]
```

Comment: Please replace image with its text. See: [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is you create a .bashrc file under /home/releases, yet you are using root user. When root user starts the bash program, the file /root/.bashrc is sourced, not /home/releases/.bashrc

Either create a non-root "release" user or move your alias to the root .bashrc

Answer (score 1):

You need

1. Understand what user running inside Docker container
2. Check permissions for it (they must be right i.e user inside Docker must have access to .bashrc)
3. Use absolute path .bashrc (i.e /home/user/.bashrc)